# RegionDifference for Cylinder and Cuboid

Tags: regions

I wish to use `RegionDifference` to take a cube shape out of a cylinder. First I make the cylinder and cube and combine them in `RegionUnion.`

```
reg1 = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {10, 0, 0}}, 0.5];
reg2 = Cuboid[{5, 0, 0}, {10, 1, 1}];
Region[RegionUnion[reg1, reg2], Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So this looks good so far. Now I wish to take the cuboid out of the cylinder leaving a notch in the cylinder. I try

```
reg = RegionDifference[reg1, reg2];
Region[reg, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

My cylinder is chopped off short and given a bad end (away from the subtraction). Is there a workaround?

Version 11.3 for windows.

Comment: Wow, that's _really_ weird. Please contact support. Honestly, I am quite disappointed with the almost nonexistent usability of the `BooleanRegion` facilities.

Comment: I have sent it off to support.I agree about being fed up. Second time in two days you have had to help me out -for which I am very grateful.

Answer (score 8):

Please note the `RegionBounds`:

```
reg1 = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {10, 0, 0}}, 0.5];
reg2 = Cuboid[{5, 0, 0}, {10, 1, 1}];
reg = RegionDifference[reg1, reg2];

bounds = RegionBounds@reg;
Region[reg, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> bounds]
```

[image]

Comment: Whoa. Why did `PlotRange -> All` not work? Anyways, good job!

Comment: I put in PlotRange All because I wondered if it was a plotting problem. Are there known issues with PlotRange?

Comment: @Hugh How Mathematica works is probably only known to the developers. For the user remains only trial and error. But I have already encountered this problem earlier. You have sent it off to support, that's ok.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be a viable workaround although it is a shame that we have to discretize the cylinder that early.

```
reg1 = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {10, 0, 0}}, 0.5], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001];
reg2 = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Cuboid[{5, 0, 0}, {10, 1, 1}]];
reg = RegionDifference[reg1, reg2]
```

[image]

As a rule of thumb, I would strongly discourage applying boolean operations to graphics primitives and everything else which is neither a `MeshRegion` nor a `BoundaryMeshRegion`.

Comment: @JasonB. Thank you for the edit. That was an error that I make too often...