# How do I properly define and work with region unions?

Tags: regions, geometry, mesh, discretization

Suppose I have two regions defined by two hexahedrons (slightly adapted from [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/211524/what-can-we-expect-from-boolean-region-operations)):

```
hexpts = {{1.7, 1.5, 0}, {1.7, 10.8, 0}, {20.3, 10.8, 0.01}, {20.3, 
    1.5, 0}, {1.7, 1.5, 0.6}, {1.7, 10.8, 0.6}, {20.3, 10.8, 
    0.6}, {20.3, 1.5, 0.6}};
reg = Hexahedron[Rationalize[hexpts]];
hexpts2 = {{1.7, 1.5, 0}, {1.7, 10.8, 0}, {20.3, 10.8, 0.01}, {20.3, 
     1.5, 0}, {1.7, 1.5, 0.6}, {1.7, 10.8, 0.6}, {20.3, 10.8, 
     0.6}, {20.3, 1.5, 0.6}} + 0.1;
reg2 = Hexahedron[Rationalize[hexpts2]];
Region@reg
```

[image]

Now I am interested in the `RegionUnion` of both:

```
myreg = RegionUnion[reg, reg2]
Region@myreg
```

[image]

Then all 3 regions are `Regions` and also bounded regions:

```
list = {reg, reg2, myreg};
RegionQ[#] & /@ list
BoundedRegionQ[#] & /@ list
```

> {True, True, True}

> {True, True, True}

But I cannot calculate the volume nor other region parameters for the region union:

```
Volume[#] & /@ list
```

> {103.211, 103.211,
> Volume[BooleanRegion[#1 || #2 &, {Hexahedron[{{17/10, 3/2, 0}, {17/
> 10, 54/5, 0}, {203/10, 54/5, 1/100}, {203/10, 3/2, 0}, {17/10,
> 3/2, 3/5}, {17/10, 54/5, 3/5}, {203/10, 54/5, 3/5}, {203/10, 3/
> 2, 3/5}}],
> Hexahedron[{{9/5, 8/5, 1/10}, {9/5, 109/10, 1/10}, {102/5, 109/10,
> 11/100}, {102/5, 8/5, 1/10}, {9/5, 8/5, 7/10}, {9/5, 109/10,
> 7/10}, {102/5, 109/10, 7/10}, {102/5, 8/5, 7/10}}]}]]}

I tried discretizing the region union but it failed with:

```
 DiscretizeRegion@myreg
```

> DiscretizeRegion::regpnd: A non-degenerate region is expected at position 1 of DiscretizeRegion[BooleanRegion[#1||#2&,{Hexahedron[{{17/10,3/2,0},{17/10,54/5,0},{203/10,54/5,1/100},{203/10,3/2,0},{17/10,3/2,3/5},{17/10,54/5,3/5},{203/10,54/5,3/5},{203/10,3/2,3/5}}],Hexahedron[{{9/5,8/5,1/10},{9/5,109/10,1/10},{102/5,109/10,11/100},{102/5,8/5,1/10},{9/5,8/5,7/10},{9/5,109/10,7/10},{102/5,109/10,7/10},{102/5,8/5,7/10}}]}]].

An error message that was raised in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/211524/what-can-we-expect-from-boolean-region-operations) but the proposed solution (using `Rationalize`) isn't applicable for general `Hexahedron`s as it seems (note that I changed `0` to `0.01` in `hexpts[[3,3]]`)

**How do I properly define the `RegionUnion` of `reg` and `reg2` so I can use `Volume`, `RegionCentroid` etc on it?**

Comment: It seems that "Volume" together with "RegionUnion" does not work properly. E.g. Volume[RegionUnion[Cube[], Ball[0.5 {1, 1, 1}]]]  gives an infinite volume.

Comment: This totally unrelated to your question, but how did you get this pdf figure in your question?  I've tried and stack  exchange won't let me.

Comment: I think you've found a bug. `DiscretizeRegion` should work.

Comment: @Chris : I just dragged a file into the browser.

Comment: @m_goldberg : yes, however I changed the regularity of this hexagon a bit compared to the other question. If you change the value 0.01 to 0 `DiscretizeRegion` works. Any idea why?

Comment: @MrPuh. A displacement of .01 requires a very fine mesh. When the two plates are fully aligned, then the union is sane as one of the plates and so the mesh that worked for one of the plates will work for the union. I think that might be the issue or part of it, but can' t be sure. Suggest you contact Wolfram tech support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ConvexHullMesh` on the hexahedron points, yields equivalent results.

```
ps1 = {{1.7, 1.5, 0}, {1.7, 10.8, 0}, {20.3, 10.8, 0.01}, {20.3, 1.5, 
    0}, {1.7, 1.5, 0.6}, {1.7, 10.8, 0.6}, {20.3, 10.8, 0.6}, {20.3, 
    1.5, 0.6}};
ps2 = ps1 + 0.1;
ch1 = ConvexHullMesh@ps1;
ch2 = ConvexHullMesh@ps2;
uch = RegionUnion[ch1, ch2];
RegionCentroid@uch
Volume@uch
```

> {11.0386, 6.19422, 0.350848}

> 122.174

`Hexahedron` can be used with `RegionUnion` and `Volume`, see example below. So I suspect something might be funky in your point data.

```
ps0 = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 
    1}, {2, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}};
ps1 = #*{1.8, 0.9, 0.5} & /@ ps0;
ps2 = #*{1.2, 1.5, 1.8} + 0.3 & /@ ps0;
h1 = Hexahedron@ps1;
h2 = Hexahedron@ps2;
uh = RegionUnion[h1, h2];
RegionCentroid@uh
Volume@uh
Graphics3D@uh
```

> {1.56298, 0.93645, 1.01992}

> 3.9852

[image]