# RegionIntersection returns unevaluated for 3D regions

Tags: regions

I'm trying to find the volume an ellipsoid and a prism share. I tried using `RegionIntersection`, but it returns unevaluated.
Input:

```
sample3D=Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {572, 96, 572}];
beam3D=Prism[{{2864.79, 0, -2810}, {0, 10.0001, -2810}, {-2864.79, 
   0, -2810}, {2864.79, 0, 2810}, {0, 10.0001, 2810}, {-2864.79, 0, 
   2810}}];
Volume@RegionIntersection[beam3D, sample3D]
```

Returns:

```
Volume[BooleanRegion[#1 && #2 &, {Prism[{{1145.93, 0, -2810}, {0, 
      10.0004, -2810}, {-1145.93, 0, -2810}, {1145.93, 0, 2810}, {0, 
      10.0004, 2810}, {-1145.93, 0, 2810}}], 
   Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {572, 96, 572}]}]]
```

Both the ellipsoid and prism are of the same dimension and are recognized by `RegionQ` as regions.

A two-dimensional example of a triangle and an ellipse works fine. Input:

```
sample2D=Disk[{0, 0}, {572, 10}];
beam2D=Triangle[{{2864.79, 0}, {0, 10.0001}, {-2864.79, 0}}];
Area@RegionIntersection[sample2D, beam2D]
```

Returns:

```
8927.06
```

I already read somewhere, that Mathematica versions below 11.3 had problems with `Region` functions, but I'm using version 12.0.

Thanks a bunch in advance!

**Edit:**

The original problem can be worked around by applying `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` to both regions. Input:

```
sample3D$edit1 = 
  BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {572, 96, 572}];
beam3D$edit1 = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@
   Prism[{{2864.79, 0, -2810}, {0, 10.0001, -2810}, {-2864.79, 
      0, -2810}, {2864.79, 0, 2810}, {0, 10.0001, 2810}, {-2864.79, 0,
       2810}}];
Volume@RegionIntersection[beam3D$edit1, sample3D$edit1]
```

Returns:

```
9.37725*10^6
```

However, this only works for some points for `Prism` and not for others. Other points generate a bunch of error messages. Input:

```
sample3D$edit2 = 
  BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@
   Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {572, 96, 572}];
beam3D$edit2 = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@
   Prism[{{21824., 11.9101, -2810}, {6823.95, 38.09, -2810}, {-15000, 
  0, -2810}, {21824., 11.9101, 2810}, {6823.95, 38.09, 2810}, {-15000,
   0, 2810}}];
Volume@RegionIntersection[beam3D$edit2, sample3D$edit2]
```

Returns error messages:

```
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion::regpnd: A non-degenerate region is expected at position 1 of BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Prism[{{21824.,11.9101,-2810},{6823.95,38.09,-2810},{-15000,0,-2810},{21824.,11.9101,2810},{6823.95,38.09,2810},{-15000,0,2810}}]].
RegionIntersection::reg: BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Prism[{{21824.,11.9101,-2810},{6823.95,38.09,-2810},{-15000,0,-2810},{21824.,11.9101,2810},{6823.95,38.09,2810},{-15000,0,2810}}]] is not a correctly specified region.
Volume::reg: RegionIntersection[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Prism[{{21824.,11.9101,-2810},{6823.95,38.09,-2810},{-15000,0,-2810},{21824.,11.9101,2810},{6823.95,38.09,2810},{-15000,0,2810}}]],] is not a correctly specified region.
```

Inspired by [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/211524/what-can-we-expect-from-boolean-region-operations/211529#211529) answer I added `Rationalize` to the Prisms points and this works for most of my applications, albeit rather slowly. Input:

```
sample3D$edit3 := 
  BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {572, 96, 572}];
beam3D$edit3 := 
  BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@
   Prism[Rationalize[{{150739.44950992631`, 
       23.691003428484592`, -2810}, {135739.44950992634`, 
       26.308997333058976`, -2810}, {-15000, 
       0, -2810}, {150739.44950992631`, 23.691003428484592`, 
       2810}, {135739.44950992634`, 26.308997333058976`, 
       2810}, {-15000, 0, 2810}}, 0]];
 Volume@RegionIntersection[beam3D$edit3, sample3D$edit3] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Returns:

```
{11.139, 486462.}
```

Eventhough this works, it is too slow for my ultimate goal and still returns error messages for some points:

```
BoundaryMeshRegion::bsuncl: The boundary surface is not closed because the edges Line[{{763,315},{316,763},{315,316}}] only come from a single face.
```

Comment: In Version 13.0 I get a result with: `Volume[MeshRegion[NDSolve`FEM`ToElementMesh[RegionIntersection[beam3D, sample3D]]]]`

Comment: Strange, I have also version 13.0 on Windows 10 and get the same output like rowsi

Comment: `DiscretizeRegion[beam3D]` also hangs on 13.0 which isn't great even if you just wanted an approximate result. Wolfram needs better QA for basic cases like this :(

Comment: @flinty, don't misunderstand me this should work and I have reported that internally, but it's certainly not a basic case. The number of characters needed to show an issue does not say anything about the complexity to solve the issue; especially in the wolfram language.

Comment: @DanielHuber, does the version I posted does not work for you in V13?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments so far. I have been able to get a result by applying `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` to both regions. Eventhough it works for the points mentioned in my question, it still doesn't evaluate for others. I'll update my question accordingly.

Comment: @user21 Sadly, I am not able to upgrade to 13.0 as there are some issues with access to the data on our network drive at my institution with this version. Local copies of my notebooks would work, but administrator credentials aren't available to me. I contacted our IT guys to resolve the issue.

Comment: Hi rowsi, I recommend when you update your post to include different versions of such things as `beam3D` and related terms, you separate their definitions out by changing the names. For example, `beam3D$edit1` and so-on. That way, future users who want to help you can better differentiate between what is working and what isn’t, and then reference these things in their answers. Can you, please, make this update?

Comment: @CATrevillian edited as per your suggestion. Thanks a bunch, gonna keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: @user21  As I wrote, I do not get your result but the result rowsi gets.

Comment: With version 13.0.0 ``Volume[MeshRegion[NDSolve`FEM`ToElementMesh[RegionIntersection[beam3D, sample3D]]]]`` returns `9.33744*10^6` for the original input. But for `sample3D$edit2` and `beam3D$edit2` it doesn't work (both with and without `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix my problem with a workaround. It consists of two changes to my original problem:

First I split the `Prism` from my original problem into two prisms whose intersection formed the original prism.
Second, I switched from `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` to `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics`, which works a lot faster. I also added `MaxCellMeasure->0.05` to my `Ellipsoid`. Both higher and lower values for `MaxCellMeasure` give the error message:

```
BoundaryMeshRegion::bsuncl :  The boundary surface is not closed because the edges Line[...] only come from a single face.
```

But 0.05 seems to be a "sweetspot" and all calculations for my application work with this value.
The now working piece looks like this:

```
incPrism := 
  BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
   Prism[Rationalize[Join[incPrismPtsNegative, incPrismPtsPositive], 
     0]]];
outPrism := 
  BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
   Prism[Rationalize[Join[outPrismPtsNegative, outPrismPtsPositive], 
     0]]];
sample3D := 
 BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
  Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {SampleWidth/2, SampleHeight, SampleWidth/2}], 
  MaxCellMeasure -> 0.05]
ParallelTable[
 Volume@RegionIntersection[outPrism, sample3D], {alpha, 
  0.01 \[Degree], 0.2 \[Degree], 0.01 \[Degree]}]
ParallelTable[
 Volume@RegionIntersection[incPrism, sample3D], {alpha, 
  0.01 \[Degree], 0.2 \[Degree], 0.01 \[Degree]}]
```

With `SampleWidth` and `SampleHeight` being non-negative numbers for the ellipsoids radii, `incPrismPtsNegative`, `incPrismPtsPositive`, `outPrismPtsNegative` and `outPrismPtsPositive` being the corresponding points for `incPrism` and `outPrism`, which are dependant on the angle `alpha`, which is used in `ParallelTable`.
Returns:

```
{2.63661*10^6, 5.26535*10^6, 7.88319*10^6, 1.04872*10^7, 1.30742*10^7,
  1.56414*10^7, 1.81854*10^7, 2.07027*10^7, 2.31899*10^7, 
 2.56421*10^7, 2.80515*10^7, 3.04142*10^7, 3.27272*10^7, 3.49878*10^7,
  3.71931*10^7, 3.93402*10^7, 4.14256*10^7, 4.34455*10^7, 
 4.53931*10^7, 4.55803*10^7}
{4.55883*10^7, 4.55883*10^7, 4.55882*10^7, 4.5588*10^7, 4.55878*10^7, 
 4.55876*10^7, 4.55873*10^7, 4.5587*10^7, 4.55867*10^7, 4.55863*10^7, 
 4.55859*10^7, 4.5585*10^7, 4.55849*10^7, 4.55844*10^7, 4.55838*10^7, 
 4.55832*10^7, 4.55825*10^7, 4.55818*10^7, 4.55811*10^7, 4.55803*10^7}
```

Thanks a lot for your comments everyone!

**Edit**

With further tinkering I found that `MaxCellMeasure->0.05` is not the be-all and end-all to my problem. However, playing around with the value for `MaxCellMeasure` gives satisfactory results most of the time. For my application I still count this as a success.